# pip installing a github library

Tags: python, github, pip

I'm trying to use https://github.com/Dimitri-Gnidash/django-js-utils

I've tried

```
ubuntu13:~/Documents/momsplanner/momsite/momsite/bin$ pip install git+https://github.com/Dimitri-Gnidash/django-js-utils.git Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/Dimitri-Gnidash/django-js-utils.git   Cloning https://github.com/Dimitri-Gnidash/django-js-utils.git to /tmp/pip-ih5kUo-build   Running setup.py egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/Dimitri-Gnidash/django-js-utils.git
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-ih5kUo-build/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-ih5kUo-build/setup.py'

---------------------------------------- Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-ih5kUo-build
```

So this github library is not meant to be used this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not have a `setup.py`, I doubt it is gonna work, you will probably need to clone it and add to your path.

related: [PIP install a Python Package without a setup.py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204811/pip-install-a-python-package-without-a-setup-py-file#2205586)